# How to Set Struct Values Outside the Class?

Tags: swift, xcode, data-structures, struct, singleton

I've got a struct in my singleton class and I'm trying to set the values in a different class. I tried setting it like I'd set any other variable in the singleton class but i get an error ***"Static member 'bigStruct', cannot be used on instance of type "SharingManager" "***

I tried -

```
let sm = SharingManager.sharedInstance  

sm.bigStruct //Autocomplete doesn't work and i get an error
```

Then when I add **line 15** in the singleton class, I can't set it because i get the error ***"Cannot assign to property: function calls immutable value"*** (From what i undertab this mens that it makes a copy of the struct so it can be viewed but not set)

```
sm.bigStruct.smallStruct.init().name = "my name"
```

**Singleton Class -**

```
class SharingManager {  
  struct bigStruct {              
    struct smallStruct {  
      var name = String()       
    }      
  }   
  static let sharedInstance = SharingManager()  
  var big = bigStruct.self    
}
```

My singleton class works fine for normal variables but I can't find how to set a struct in a singleton class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
var big = SharingManager.bigStruct()
var small = SharingManager.bigStruct.smallStruct()
small.name = "I am a smallStruct"
```

---

The following can't work because `bigStruct`/`smallStruct` are not instance properties or functions:

> SharingManager.sharedInstance.bigStruct
>
> SharingManager.sharedInstance.bigStruct.smallStruct.init().name = "my name"